# Retrieve google map coordinates on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I need to extract coordinates from google maps in such a way that when I click the location on the map the coordinates get stored in a variable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you have any relevant code to start with?

Comment: If only there was some sort of documentation - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: Presumably you're using the JS API v3 to add a map to your site, right @Milap?

Comment: im trying to integrate the maps to an application not a website@duncan

Comment: basically my assignment is to link the google maps(somehow), get the coordinates store them in variables, burn that code into a microcontroller and calculate distance and various typical measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    // you can store event.latLng object in your variable
    // it returns an object like
    // rf {A: 51.510077954475555, F: -0.06484508514404297}
    console.log(event.latLng);
});
```